# Как добавлять рекламные аккаунты в приложение facebook по api

Tags: api, facebook

У меня есть вопрос касаемо facebook api.
В панели доп настроек для приложения есть поле для добавления  авторизованных рекламных аккаунтов. (на скрине).
Может ли кто-то подсказать, как добавлять эти аккаунты средствами api fb. В документации я нашел только метод get как получать список этих акков.
Заранее спасибо.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Переведите ваш вопрос на русский, пожалуйста

Comment: у тебя получилось решить проблему?

Comment: По прежнему простого метода я не увидел. Ищу решение...(

Comment: Так же интересует данные вопрос, подайте идею для реализации